# How to configure parent pom.xml for jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, pom.xml

I have a scenario,
I have a repository in Bitbucket say `Mywebapp`. `Mywebap` consist two dependent maven project, say `Project_A` and `Project_B`.  Both projects have their own `pom.xml` file inside `Project_A` and `Project_B`.

When we try to deploy any project from Jenkins we get the `URL` from Bitbucket is, like this **`git@bitbucket.org:user_name/repository_name.git`**.
Bitbucket does not provide the `URL` for projects instead repository.

If we create any repository and we push are code, repository has to have the `pom.xml` file, then only Jenkins is able to build the project.

So coming to the question, When I paste this `URL` `git@bitbucket.org:user_name/repository_name.git` in `Jenkins`. Jenkins throws and error saying `pom.xml is not found`, and it should; because pom.xml file are inside `Project_A` and `Project_B`. and the `URL` is upto repository.

So is there any way that I will have a repository and inside I will have multiple projects and project will have their own `pom.xml` file. 
And in the repository, I will have one parent `pom.xml` file in repository which will consist both`project_A's` and `project_B's` `pom.xml` in parent `pom.xml` file reside in repository.
If yes then how can I achieve this.

Any suggestion, dock, link is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should create parent pom.xml in the root directory of your repository and add following configuration to it:

```
<modules>
    <module>project_A</module>
    <module>project_B</module>
</modules>
```

Where `project_A` and `project_B` are folders names of the projects. To check if everything works you can run in the root dir:

```
mvn package
```

If it's OK, you'll see both your projects in Maven reactor (`Reactor Build Order`)

Comment: Ho to trigger a multi branch approach this way?